# How to get the value of a variable from a tkinter application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need some help with my code, here is a part of it I am struggling with, (so many excess libraries, I know). I need to get the value of `zxc` out of code and be able to operate with it outside of the function.

I was trying `asking()` , `print(asking())`, I even tried to add it to a list and then extract it out, it just writes the same problem, could anyone suggest me something?

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import simpledialog
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo


def goback():
    choiceframe.pack()
    win.destroy()
def goback2():
    win2.destroy()
    root.destroy()
def kekes():
    win = tk.Toplevel(root, command = showinfo())
    win.wm_title("Error")

def asking():
    global win,win2
    zxc = simpledialog.askinteger("input string", " Choose 1 / 2")
    if zxc == 1 or zxc == 2:
        print(zxc)
        win2 = tk.Toplevel()
        win2.wm_title("Great Choice")
        bbok = tk.Button(win2, text = f'Selected {zxc}', command = goback2)
        bbok.pack()
        return zxc
    else:
        win = tk.Toplevel()
        win.wm_title("Error")
        bok = tk.Button(win,text = "Try Again! Insert other value", command = goback)
        bok.pack()

        return 0


root = tk.Tk()
choiceframe = tk.Frame(root,bg = "#E2DEDE")
choiceframe.place(relwidth = 0.2, relheight = 0.05, relx = 0.675, rely = 0.2)
choiceframe.pack()
B1 = tk.Button(choiceframe, bg = 'white',text = 'Make your choice ', command = asking)
B1.pack(expand = 1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The return values of callback functions like `asking()` are ignored by tkinter (which is what calls them). To work around that, you will need to either use a global variable or create a class that represents the tkinter application. How do you intend on using the value of this variable?

Comment: This entire code is to determinate in my GUI mini game who will make the first shot in Russian Rullete, i havemt learned classes yet, so i would rather not use them. I will need this value to be used in another function. kind of ```def game(zxc)```

Comment: In that case add a `global zxc` statement to the beginning of the `asking()` function (and remove the `return` statements since they don't accomplish anything). This will allow you to reference the variable's current value from anywhere in the script (after it's assigned one anyway) — so you won't need to pass it as an argument to the `game()` function.

Comment: it works thank you a lot

Comment: That's good to hear. Suggest you learn how to use classes asap because they're not really that hard and will make writing most code a lot easier.